# When I use document.write function and I want to when this event happen some CSS is working on but I can not add CSS while using classlist

Tags: javascript

when I use `document.write` function and I want to when this event happens some CSS is working on but I can not add CSS while using `classlist`.

```js
var login = document.getElementById('login');
var sign = document.getElementById('sign');

login.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var name1 = document.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].value;
  var pass = document.getElementsByClassName('name')[1].value;

  var chan = document.writeln(name1);
  chan.classList.add('change');

  var chan2 = document.write(pass);
});
```

Comment: don't use `document.write` to *update* the DOM - use console.log for debugging, use DOM methods/properties (createElement, appendChild, .innerHTML etc etc) to update the DOM

Comment: You seem to be struggling a little with JavaScript. [The MDN documentation for JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) might help you.